# Firebase - Error: download failed, expected 64907894 bytes but got 64723779

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I've been trying to setup a local Firebase Emulator Suite, but I'm unable to understand why this is throwing this strange error, a help will be very much appreciated.

```
? Which Firebase emulators do you want to set up? Press Space to select emulators, then Enter to confirm your choices. Authentication 
Emulator, Functions Emulator, Firestore Emulator, Database Emulator, Hosting Emulator, Pub/Sub Emulator, Storage Emulator, Eventarc   
Emulator
? Which port do you want to use for the auth emulator? 9099
? Which port do you want to use for the functions emulator? 5001
? Which port do you want to use for the firestore emulator? 8080
? Which port do you want to use for the database emulator? 9000
? Which port do you want to use for the hosting emulator? 5000
? Which port do you want to use for the pubsub emulator? 8085
? Which port do you want to use for the storage emulator? 9199
? Which port do you want to use for the eventarc emulator? 9299
? Would you like to enable the Emulator UI? Yes
? Which port do you want to use for the Emulator UI (leave empty to use any available port)?
? Would you like to download the emulators now? Yes
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.17.2.jar...
Progress: ===========================================================================================================> (100% of 65MB) 

Error: download failed, expected 64907894 bytes but got 64723779
```

I started with

`firebase init emulators`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of firebase-tools had a bug where the size and hash didn't match the downloaded emulator, see the following issue for more details:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5734

As of right now, updating to the newest version 11.29.1 should resolve the download issue.